# Java averaging calculator with defined number of entries

Tags: java

I've seen several average calculators but none with this specific function.
Basically, I want it to ask "How many numbers would you like to average?" then "Enter your number" and continue to prompt "Enter your number" after each entry until the "How many numbers..." quantity is fulfilled. I know it's a count-loop (sorry if my jargon is off...I'm only in my second semester of computer programming) but I don't know how to set it up. Thanks in advance for your answers. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoreApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // welcome the user to the program
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Test Average Calculator!");
        System.out.println();  // print a blank line
        // display operational messages
        System.out.println("Please enter test scores that range from 0 to 100.");
        System.out.println();  // print a blank line

        // initialize variables and create a Scanner object
        int scoreTotal;
        int scoreCount;
        int testScore;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // perform calculations until choice isn't equal to "y" or "Y"
        String choice = "y";
        while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            // get the number of grades to be averaged from the user
            System.out.print("How many scores would you like to average? ");
            scoreCount = sc.nextInt();

            // get the input from the user
            System.out.print("Enter score: ");
            testScore = sc.nextInt();

            // accumulate score count and score total
            if (testScore <= 100)
            {
                scoreTotal = scoreTotal + testScore;
            }
            else if (testScore >= 100)
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, not counted");


        // display the score count, score total, and average score
        double averageScore = scoreTotal / scoreCount;
        String message = "\n" +
                         "Score count:   " + scoreCount + "\n"
                       + "Score total:   " + scoreTotal + "\n"
                       + "Average score: " + averageScore + "\n";
        System.out.println(message);

        System.out.print("Would you like to average more grades? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems you already have a loop. Why not add an appropriate condition to it so that it stops after you have read the required number of scores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is near about right except some mistakes. You want to take input until `'n'` is pressed and then the average would be shown. That means the **average calculation must be done outside the loop**, when taking input ends.

If you want to take input with a predefined number from input instead of 'y'/'n' approach, you can reuse your while loop:

```
int numOfInput = sc.nextInt(); // how many number will be entered 
while(numOfInput > 0) {
   // take every input and add to total
   --numOfInput;
}
// average calculation
```

Also, a little logical mistake in input validation check.

```
if (testScore <= 100) // for less or equal 100
{
    scoreTotal = scoreTotal + testScore;
}
else if (testScore >= 100) // for greater or equal 100
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, not counted");
```

*Both condition checks whether the number is equal to 100*, which is not expected. If you allow only number less than 100, then you could write:

```
if (testScore < 100) {
    scoreTotal += testScore;
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, not counted");
}
```

Comment: Thank you all so much! This has been very helpful! Definitely given me some options. I'll try some of the changes and see if I can make them work.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to average `scoreCount` items, or keep averaging until the user has input **"n"** ?

If it's the first case (As you've described in your question) and you want to average for `scoreCount` times, you need to change the condition on your `while` loop.

```
System.out.print("How many scores would you like to average? ");
scoreCount = sc.nextInt();
scoreTotal = 0;
for(int i=0; i<scoreCount; i++){
     scoreTotal += sc.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Okay please enter next...");        
}
System.out.print("Average is " + scoreTotal/scoreCount);
```

If you want to do it with a `while`, just keep an index, `int index=0;`, increment the index on each iteration and check if you've exceeded the index.

```
while (index < scoreCount)
    scoreTotal += sc.nextInt();
    index++;
System.out.print("Average is " + scoreTotal/scoreCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what you need:

```
for( int i = 0; i < scoreCount; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter score: ");    
    testScore = sc.nextInt();
}
```

The for loop creates integer *i* to hold its looping index

```
int i;
```

And each loop asks is *i* bigger than *scoreCount* and if not loop again.

```
i < scoreCount;
```

And after each loop it adds one to *i*.

```
i++
```